# Capital In User Input Creating Traceback Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, lowercase

I have a simple piece of code where you input a name to receive further information about that person. Eg you enter 'john' for information on John. However, if a user inputs 'John' or 'JOHN' for example I get the following traceback error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    John
NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

I have been able to insert `.lower()` into my code in places (currently removed) without error however it still does not accept 'John'/'JOHN' etc, and returns all of the information about John in lowercase - which is not what I want.

Is it possible to allow the user to input using capitals? I am very new to Python and appreciate this is very straight forward, and I have seen similar threads with `.lower()` and `input().lower()` replies and similar, but struggling to work out where to include that in my code to allow for the user to input 'John' etc. Thanks.

```
class Employees:

    def __init__(self, name, lastname, age, department):
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.department = department
    def displayEmployees(self):
        return("The employee is called " + self.name + ' ' + self.lastname + " and is " + str(self.age) + " years old, and works in the " + self.department + " department.")

employee1 = Employees("Sam", "Smith", 25, "Office")

employee2 = Employees("John", "Smith", 23, "Admin")

employee3 = Employees("Amy", "Smith", 28, "Admin")

employee4 = Employees("Alice", "Smith", 30, "Reception")

employee5 = Employees("Chris", "Smith", 51, "Managers")

sam = employee1.displayEmployees()

john = employee2.displayEmployees()

amy = employee3.displayEmployees()

alice = employee4.displayEmployees()

chris = employee5.displayEmployees()


print("Please input the first name of the employee you wish to find out more about the employee")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
name = input('Please enter the persons name').lower()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have replaced the print("Please input...") with that, however it still doesnt work. It generates in blue 'Please enter the persons name' when run, then i enter their name and press enter then I end up on the line with '>>>' only then if i enter in lower case do i get the persons info, if i do 'John' etc i still get traceback error.

Comment: You would need to write a function to search for the correct object and print the required values.

Comment: I can already get it to output the information when i write the name in lowercase after '>>>' in the shell. So im guessing i need to reference that somehow from the input function? Im a little unsure of how to do this, as this so far is the most complex thing ive done and I am aware of all the little bits, but now trying to put them together

Comment: Python uses case sensitive variable names, so you can't use John and john to mean the same thing. I suggest if you want input from a user you should use the input function and then search. Using the prompt is not a suitable way of interacting with a program.